# Listen for taps anywhere in a react native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, events

On the web, if a component lower down in the hierarchy needs to listen for clicks anywhere on the page, it can simply add an event listener in `componentWillMount()`:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', () => { ... })
```

Is there a corresponding solution in React Native? I know that I can have a top-level view listen for all press events, but I'm looking for a solution that avoids having to go through a top-level view. In the way that a component anywhere in the hierarchy can add an event listener on the `document` in web code, I'd like to do the same with a react native component.

Comment: Did you end up finding an alternative solution to this that fits your requirement or did you go with a top-level view? I'm encountering the same problem

Answer (score -1):

Many visible UI components have an `onPress` prop that accepts a callback function. Simply pass in the callback you want to be fired:

```
...
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("You pressed me!")}>
    <Text>Button</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Some components have variations on this for specific types of touch, like `onLongPress` and `onSlidingComplete`, to name a few. Read up on the [Components and APIs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/components-and-apis.html).

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue of being able to listen for presses anywhere. It will only work for the part of the component hierarchy inside the component that implements onPress.